# Count number of overlapping minutes between two timedate ranged

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet whereby I have an event start and end date. I want to produce a number of minutes result grouped by a date range. The result will be 8 hour chunks, for example I want to know how many minutes of the event are in the range:
15:00 until 23:00,
23:00 until 07:00, 
07:00 until 15:00.

So an event which starts at 16:00 and finishes at 23:30 ( 7 hours 30 minutes total length ) would fit into the 15:00 - 23:00 and have a value of '7' hours. The event would also have 0.5 result hours in the 23:00 until 07:00 group.

here is an example screenshot of what I have, and what I expect the values to be

[image]
What sort of formula do I need to put into my three grouped time range cells to get the results I want? ( use columns A-G for reference ).

Thanks

Edit: copy/paste of an example spreadsheet:

[link to example spreadsheet for copy paste](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ9vX/)

Just copy the output table js fiddle has created and paste into excel.

Raw code:

```
start   end duration    minutes dur 15:00 until 23:00   23:00 until 07:00   07:00 until 15:00
08/12/2013 14:15    08/12/2013 17:15    03:00   180         
08/12/2013 12:00    08/12/2013 15:00    03:00   180         
08/12/2013 11:30    08/12/2013 14:10    02:40   160         
08/12/2013 11:30    08/12/2013 14:10    02:40   160         
08/12/2013 00:00    08/12/2013 03:00    03:00   180         
07/12/2013 19:45    08/12/2013 02:00    06:15   375         
07/12/2013 17:15    07/12/2013 20:15    03:00   180         
07/12/2013 14:55    07/12/2013 17:55    03:00   180         
07/12/2013 14:30    07/12/2013 17:10    02:40   160         
07/12/2013 14:30    07/12/2013 17:10    02:40   160
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We look at two periods of time, S (=sample) and R (=reference) and their begins (B) and ends (E)

```
Reference      x-----x         x-----x     x-----x     x-----x
                               ooo  oo       ooo       ooooooo
Sample     1-1         2-2   3---3  4--4     5-5     6---------6
```

looking at the cases we can say that

- if ES < BR OR BS >= BR ... there's no overlap (cases 1, 2)
- in all other cases the period of overlap starts at MAX(BR, BS) and ends at MIN(ER, ES)

additionally, as the reference periods roll over midnight, we must "normalize" sample and reference times.

The reference times are entered as

- 0th period: BR `=0+7/24`, ER `=0+15/24`  ... we start with the lowest day time
- 1st period: BR `=0+15/24`, ER `=0+23/24`
- 2nd period: BR `=0+23/24`, ER `=1+7/24`
- 3rd period: BR `=1+7/24`, ER `=1+15/24`  ... to capture periods rolling over

(in case of very large sample periods maybe another 15-23 period for day-1 must be included)

The sample times are normalized as

- BS(norm) `=BS-INT(BS)`    ... to get rid of the date part
- ES(norm) `=ES-INT(BS)`    ... minus begin date to catch date rollover's !!!

applying the above cases the overlapping intervals can be calculated as

- F4: `=A4-INT(A4)`
- G4: `=B4-INT(A4)`
- I4 .. L4: `=IF(OR($G4<I$2;$F4>=I$3);0;MIN(I$3;$G4)-MAX(I$2;$F4))`

(all formulas copy-proof for across/down copy)

[image]

I hope I didn't overlook any special cases ....

There are of course limitations, e.g. sample periods larger than all 4 reference periods together will not be handled properly, because they will fall twice or even more often into the same reference period which is not handled by this (except if you keep adding more periods to the right for day 1, 2, 3, ... - not very sexy) ... if this is a case to be considered it's time to look at a VBA solution instead.

Comment: Hello, mate, thanks for your response. I believe you are using ";" instead of using "," for your logical conditions ( OR IF MIN MAX ) etc. Replace ";"  with ",". Edit.

Comment: Hello, It doesn't seem to account for events that start with the time of 00:00. For example: Start: "02/12/2013 00:00" end time: "01/12/2013 03:00".

Comment: sorry yes ... I use German locale, hence ";" instead of "," and I always forget to convert .... and yes the example mentioned in your comment is not covered because SE < SB ... and yes you're right because the 0 hours appears only in day 1 ... not in day 0 ... week point ... thinking

Comment: My extremely 'unsexy' way around this problem is to create to helper columns to create the 23:00 -> 07:00. I have a column which is `0 23:00` to `1 00:00` and one other column which is `0 00:00` to `0 07:00`. I then add these columns together to get 0 23:00 until 07:00 ...

Comment: that's not as unsexy as it seems ... I have done a 2nd round in my example, too ... I guess you must have on slice more than the max. period you must expect